# How do I use pcre_study with pcrecpp?

Tags: c++, regex, performance, pcre

I'm using Google's C++ interface to PCRE to match a single regex multiple times (possibly thousands of times). From reading the PCRE manual, it seems like a good idea to let PCRE 'study' (spend time optimizing) the regex, however, I can't seem to find a way to do that with the C++ wrapper. The `pcrecpp.h` doesn't mention studying at all.

Is using pcre_study() worthwile, and if so, how can it be combined with pcrecpp and its RE class?

Comment: if reading the docs doesn't give clear answer, then shy away from the foul odoriferous animal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick scan of the [PCRE++ source code](http://vcs.pcre.org/viewvc/code/trunk/pcrecpp.cc?revision=881&view=markup), it appears that "studying" is impossible with this API because the compiled RE (`pcre*`) member of the `RE` wrapper object is `private` and there's no way to get it out or reset it.

If you want to know whether the studying optimization is worthwhile with your REs, the easiest option that I see is to copy `pcrecpp.{cc,h}` into your project and hack it in; the C++ API is just some thin wrapper code. You might even want to submit a patch upstream if, like me, you like to litter open source projects with your name and copyright ;)

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of people hitting on this question from a web search, I will point out that the ability to "study" an RE has been removed from PCRE2:

> 8. Explicit "studying" of compiled patterns has been abolished - it now always
>    happens automatically. JIT compiling is done by calling a new function,
>    pcre2_jit_compile() after a successful return from pcre2_compile().

Reference: https://lists.exim.org/lurker/message/20150105.162835.0666407a.en.html